# Bottom-align text in a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a website where we have rows of buttons - they are an image, then an h3, and then a button, all stacked on top of each other.

These are all displayed using flexbox and `flex-direction: column` and a series of `margin-top: auto` rules.

The h3s sometimes break onto two lines. When this happens, the button text aligns to the center of the h3 tag: sort of like a hyphen and an equal sign next to each other.

`- = =` instead of `- - -`

Client would like the bottom line of the h3 text to align. I can't figure out how to do this exactly... Can anyone help?

[image: lines of text aligned at bottom of container]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLVMPo

```css
div.row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service-square-row .span4,
.service-square-row .span3,
.service-square-row .span6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service-square-row .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services.service-square-row .span4 {
  width: 260px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #013ca6;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
}

.service-square p:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 126px;
}

.service-square-row .flex-link .span4 img,
.service-square-row .flex-link .span3 img {
  max-height: 126px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img,
video {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.service-square-row .flex-link img,
.service-square-row .flex-link img {
  height: 126px;
  width: 126px
}

.service-square-row h3 {
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.service-square-row .service-square p:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

a.btn-bt.default,
a.btn-bt.alternate {
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

a.btn-bt.alternate {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #e31d1a;
  letter-spacing: px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row three-thirds services service-square-row  default-padding light-header light-content" style="">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="flex-link" href="/electronics-restoration/">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-1 service-1" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-484" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="120" height="120"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Electronics</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="/electronics-restoration/">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex-link" href="/art-and-document-recovery/">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-2 service-2" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-485" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="106" height="139"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Art &amp; Document Recovery</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="/art-and-document-recovery/">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex-link" href="#">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-3 service-3" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-486" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="140" height="143"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Wind, Hurricane, &amp; Tornado</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="#">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Unfortunately, codepen seems to have interpreted the HTML I pasted into it differently that Wordpress did... And so the codepen I had everyone work produced solutions I couldn't use on my live site. Oh well -- I ended up figuring it out on the live site anyways. Sorry for not noticing earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the "buttons" set to column-direction flex containers:

```
.service-square-row .span4  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

But the first child (flex item) of the container is set to `flex-grow: 0`, which is the default setting. So the `h3` text has a limited range of motion.

Try this instead:

```
.span4 > .flex-link {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
}

.service-square-row .service-square p:last-child {
    /* margin-top: auto; */
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djBweE)

```css
div.row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service-square-row .span4,
.service-square-row .span3,
.service-square-row .span6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service-square-row .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services.service-square-row .span4 {
  width: 260px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #013ca6;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
}

.service-square p:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 126px;
}

.service-square-row .flex-link .span4 img,
.service-square-row .flex-link .span3 img {
  max-height: 126px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img,
video {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.service-square-row .flex-link img,
.service-square-row .flex-link img {
  height: 126px;
  width: 126px
}

.service-square-row h3 {
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.service-square-row .service-square p:last-child {
  /* margin-top: auto; */
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

a.btn-bt.default,
a.btn-bt.alternate {
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

a.btn-bt.alternate {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #e31d1a;
  letter-spacing: px;
}

.span4>.flex-link {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
  /* demo only; illustrates full range of element */
}
```

```html
<div class="row three-thirds services service-square-row  default-padding light-header light-content" style="">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="flex-link" href="/electronics-restoration/">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-1 service-1" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-484" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="120" height="120"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Electronics</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="/electronics-restoration/">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex-link" href="/art-and-document-recovery/">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-2 service-2" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-485" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="106" height="139"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Art &amp; Document Recovery</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="/art-and-document-recovery/">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex-link" href="#">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-3 service-3" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-486" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="140" height="143"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Wind, Hurricane, &amp; Tornado</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="#">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to align itself to the bottom center of a container, the route I usually take is to set the parent as `display: flex;` and the children as `align-self: flex-end;`

If you want to maintain the same structure of your HTML, the best route would be to set the height of your link container to be a percentage of the parent, align the `<h3>` to the bottom of its container, and center it.

```
.service-square .flex-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80%;
}

.service-square h3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Hopefully I understood your question correctly, let me know if you have any questions or I misunderstood the initial request.

```css
div.row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service-square-row .span4,
.service-square-row .span3,
.service-square-row .span6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service-square-row .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services.service-square-row .span4 {
  width: 260px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #013ca6;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
}

.service-square p:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 126px;
}

.service-square-row .flex-link .span4 img,
.service-square-row .flex-link .span3 img {
  max-height: 126px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img,
video {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.service-square-row .flex-link img,
.service-square-row .flex-link img {
  height: 126px;
  width: 126px
}

.service-square-row h3 {
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.service-square-row .service-square p:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

a.btn-bt.default,
a.btn-bt.alternate {
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

a.btn-bt.alternate {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #e31d1a;
  letter-spacing: px;
}

/* ===== New content ===== */

.service-square .flex-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80%;
}

.service-square h3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row three-thirds services service-square-row  default-padding light-header light-content" style="">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="flex-link" href="/electronics-restoration/">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-1 service-1" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-484" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="120" height="120"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Electronics</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="/electronics-restoration/">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex-link" href="/art-and-document-recovery/">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-2 service-2" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-485" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="106" height="139"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Art &amp; Document Recovery</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="/art-and-document-recovery/">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="flex-link" href="#">
      <div class="span4 service-square sq-3 service-3" style="border-style:;">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-486" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" width="140" height="143"></p>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Wind, Hurricane, &amp; Tornado</h3>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="btn-bt alternate" href="#">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```